# Modify current code to reject user input if > 21

Tags: java, if-statement, max, user-input

this is what I have so far, using NetBeans.

```
System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack 21!");
Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1, num2;
// Read 1st number
System.out.println("Enter 1st number");
num1 = data.nextInt();
// Read 2nd number
System.out.println("Enter 2nd number");
num2 = data.nextInt();
// Find largest number
if (num1 > num2)
    System.out.println("The largest number:" + num1);
else
    System.out.println("The largest number:" + num2);
```

All I need help with is: I need to figure out a way that doesn't allow the user to input a number greater that 21. The idea is that it's going to be a blackjack program, and so the numbers being entered by the user cannot surpass 21.

Thank you!!

Comment: You are looking for while-loops. With a while-loop you can read user input until the input is smaller or equal than 21. The user will get stuck into the loop if he input a number that is greater than 21.

Comment: you can´t directly deny him inputing anything greater then 21, you can just flag the input as not valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(num1 > 21 || num2 > 21) {
    //your code
}
```

Going off your comment if you put your code like this

```
System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack 21!");
Scanner data= new Scanner(System.in);
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
// Read 1st number
System.out.println("Enter 1st number");
num1=data.nextInt();
// Read 2nd number
System.out.println("Enter 2nd number");
num2=data.nextInt();
// Find largest number
if(num1>num2) {
    System.out.println("The largest number:"+num1);
} else {
    System.out.println("The largest number:"+num2); 
}
// If a number is too large
if(num1 > 21 || num2 > 21) {
    // Your Code
}
```

the variables `num1` and `num2` are initialised at the start

Comment: I tried this, and then NetBeans tells me "variable num1 might not have been initialized"

Comment: @PetroKo Thank you. I appreciate it :) Also I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

You just have to keep accepting the input if user is entering a number greater than 21. You can do it easily using a loop.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack 21!");

    Scanner data= new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1 = 22, num2 = 22;

    // Read 1st number
    while(data.hasNext() && num1 > 21) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1st number");
        num1 = data.nextInt();
    }

    // Read 2nd number
    while(data.hasNext() && num2 > 21) {
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number");
        num2 = data.nextInt();
    }

    // Find largest number
    if(num1 > num2) {
        System.out.println("The largest number:" + num1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The largest number:" + num2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Why is this down-voted? What is wrong here?

Comment: Removed downvote now you fixed answer. Put upvote now

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
// Read 1st number
do {
    System.out.println("Enter 1st number");
    num1 = data.nextInt();
    if (num1>21) System.out.println("Number must not be greater then 21");
} while (num1>21);
```

You will keep on looping until the user enters a valid input. Not sure if you know how a do/while works but essentially it runs the code in the `do` section and then evaluates the condition in the `while` after. Which in our case the condition is checking if the number is greater than 21. If the condition is met, it repeats what is in the `do` section, if not it will continue on with the rest of the code. Try it out for yourself with a couple of inputs.  The user can still enter a negative number so you will have to add a check for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a system that, if the user enters an invalid value, allows the user to enter a number again.

You can do this using a do-while loop:

```
int num = 0;
do {
    num = scanner.nextInt();
} while(num > 21 || num < 1);
```